# How can I remove the item in list using the comparison between list and index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This is my data frame:

```
Cites_Dogs  Dog_Number
DOG45555    DOG123
DOG127      DOG123
DOG7760     DOG126
DOG45       DOG126
DOG559      DOG126
DOG760      DOG126
DOG123      DOG127
DOG789      DOG127
DOG860      DOG127
```

I have converted to list by this code:

```
all_cites_dog = all_cites_dog.groupby('Dog_Number')['Cites_Dogs'].apply(list)
```

I would like to remove the item in the list which is not matched with the index **DOG123**, **DOG126**, **DOG127**.

```
DOG123   [ 'DOG45555' ,  'DOG127']
DOG126   [ 'DOG7760', 'DOG456' ,  'DOG559' ,  'DOG760']
DOG127   [ 'DOG123' ,  'DOG789' ,  'DOG860']
```

I would like to see the results like this:

```
DOG123   [ 'DOG127']
DOG126   ['']
DOG127   [ 'DOG123']
```

What should I do TT?

Answer (score 1):

Use filtering in `groupby+apply`:

```
idx = set(all_cites_dog['Dog_Number'])
all_cites_dog = (all_cites_dog.groupby('Dog_Number')['Cites_Dogs']
                             .apply(lambda x: list([y for y in x if y in idx])))

print (all_cites_dog)
Dog_Number
DOG123    [DOG127]
DOG126          []
DOG127    [DOG123]
Name: Cites_Dogs, dtype: object
```

For better performance first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then `groupby`, last add missing not matched empty values:

```
s = (all_cites_dog[all_cites_dog['Cites_Dogs'].isin(all_cites_dog['Dog_Number'].unique())]
             .groupby('Dog_Number')['Cites_Dogs']
             .apply(list))

idx = np.setdiff1d(all_cites_dog['Dog_Number'].unique(), s.index)
s1 = pd.Series([[]] * len(idx), index=idx)
print (s1)
DOG126    []
dtype: object

s = s.append(s1).sort_index()
print (s)
DOG123    [DOG127]
DOG126          []
DOG127    [DOG123]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and use a list comprehension to keep the elements in the index:

```
l = all_cites_dog.index
all_cites_dog.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in l])

Dog_Number
DOG123    [DOG127]
DOG126          []
DOG127    [DOG123]
Name: Cites_Dogs, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on an `isin` check.

```
(df.set_index('Dog_Number')
   .query("Cites_Dogs in index")
   .reindex(df.Dog_Number.unique()))

           Cites_Dogs
Dog_Number           
DOG123         DOG127
DOG126            NaN
DOG127         DOG123
```

If further reduction is needed, you can chain `groupby`.

```
(df.set_index('Dog_Number')
   .query("Cites_Dogs in index")
   .reindex(df.Dog_Number.unique())
   .groupby(level=0)['Cites_Dogs']
   .apply(pd.Series.tolist))

Dog_Number
DOG123    [DOG127]
DOG126       [nan]
DOG127    [DOG123]
Name: Cites_Dogs, dtype: object
```

---

Another option is `groupby` and `apply` with a set membership check.

```
s = set(df.Dog_Number)
df.groupby('Dog_Number').Cites_Dogs.apply(lambda x: x[x.isin(s)].tolist())

Dog_Number
DOG123    [DOG127]
DOG126          []
DOG127    [DOG123]
Name: Cites_Dogs, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the broad steps:

1. Filter your dataframe according to `Cites_Dogs`.
2. Perform your `groupby` + `apply` with `list`.
3. Reindex your dataframe as per unique dog numbers.
4. Replace `NaN` values with empty lists for consistency.

Here's a demonstration:

```
unq_dogs = df['Dog_Number'].unique()

res = df.loc[df['Cites_Dogs'].isin(unq_dogs]\
        .groupby('Dog_Number')['Cites_Dogs'].apply(list)\
        .reindex(unq_dogs)\
        .fillna(pd.Series([[] for _ in range(len(unq_dogs))], index=unq_dogs))\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

  Dog_Number Cites_Dogs
0     DOG123   [DOG127]
1     DOG126         []
2     DOG127   [DOG123]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works just one liner solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cites_Dogs':  ['DOG45555' ,'DOG127' , 'DOG7760' ,'DOG45','DOG559','DOG760','DOG123','DOG789','DOG860'],
               'Dog_Number': ['DOG123', 'DOG123', 'DOG126', 'DOG126', 'DOG126', 'DOG126', 'DOG127', 'DOG127', 'DOG127']})
a = ['DOG123', 'DOG126', 'DOG127']

df['Cites_Dogs'][~df['Cites_Dogs'].isin(a)] = np.nan

df.replace([np.nan], '', inplace=True)

df = df.groupby('Dog_Number')['Cites_Dogs'].apply(list)

# and output looks like this
Dog_Number
DOG123      [, DOG127]
DOG126        [, , , ]
DOG127    [DOG123, , ]
Name: Cites_Dogs, dtype: object
```

Thanks!